# div width adjustment according to the screen in vuejs but initially width is set to width.innerWidth function

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have set the width of  my div as window.innerWidth as i have to set it dynamically. now i want it to adjust it automatically depending on the screen width. example when we adjust developer option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data(){
return{
width:"";
}
},

created() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.reSizer);
},
destroyed() {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", this.reSizer);
},
methods: {
  reSizer(e) {
    // your code for handling resize...
this.width=window.innerWidth+"px";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen for screen changes, you can simply use the `resize` event:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  document.getElementById('example-div').style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
});
```